# pyqt / is there any way to change options for all keySequenceEdit boxes?

Tags: python, pyqt6

i have created 4 QKeySequenceEdits and setCleatButtonEnabled(True) for all of the four but i have to set each of the edits manually. is there an alternative command that can set every QKeySequenceEdit?

```
Pyqt.QKeySequenceEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
```

something like this would be nice.

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys
            
class MainWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test.ui",self)

        self.keySequenceEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.keySequenceEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.keySequenceEdit_3.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.keySequenceEdit_4.setClearButtonEnabled(True)




if __name__ == "__main__":

    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: [`findChildren()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#findChildren): `for edit in self.findChildren(QKeySequenceEdit):` `edit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)`.

Comment: @musicamante thank you once again!